# mysqldump asking for password even after telling it the password in the command line option

Tags: bash, command-line-interface, mysql

I am using the following command:

```
mysqldump -alv -h 123.123.123.123 --password=P@ssw0rd --user=UsernameHere --add-drop-table -p DatabaseSchemaName > dump.sql
```

Then it asks me to Enter Password.  Is there I'm doing wrong when specifying the password in the command?

The password I'm entering is definitely the proper password.

Comment: Look at your statement again. See that `-p` at the end? That's the password switch. You're overriding your original password switch on the far left because of it. (Because it's blank, it's also asking for a password)

Comment: DOH! Didn't see that thing slip in there... Reply with a proper answer and I'll give you credit. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

man mysqldump:

```
--password[=password], -p[password]

The password to use when connecting to the server. If you use the short option form (-p), you cannot have a space between the option and the password. If you omit the password value following the --password or -p option on the command line, you are prompted for one.
Specifying a password on the command line should be considered insecure. See Section 6.6, "Keeping Your Password Secure".
```

You have two password arguments:

mysqldump -alv -h 123.123.123.123 **--password**=P@ssw0rd --user=UsernameHere --add-drop-table **-p** DatabaseSchemaName > dump.sql

Remove that last argument and it should work fine.

Comment: Yeah qweet pointed that out to me above. Not sure how that slipped in there. Thanks